# Вконтакте все фотографии и к ним количество поставленных лайков в списке selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте, selenium, список

Как создать двумерный список всех фотографии для лайков и количество что уже лайкнули. Можно ли сделать это с главной страницы, с учетом того что там не только фотографии, а еще и просто записи или нужно заходить через фотографии? Через selenium
Нужен список типа:

```
buf = [[первая фотка,фотка(2),фотка(3)....][количество лайков к первой фотке,количество лайков к второй фотке,...]]
```

Чтобы обратившись

```
for i in str(len(buf[0]))): #проходимся по всем элементам что нашел    
    if buf[1][i] >= 10: #если количестов лайков больше 10, тогда лайкнуть эту фотку
        driver.find_element_by_text(buf[0][i]).click()
        #кликнул лайк



<div class="like_button_icon"></div>
<div class="like_button_label"></div>
<div class="like_button_count">78</div>
<span class="blind_label">Нравится</span>
```

Лайкает только первый элемент стены, и то не всегда:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("like_button_icon").click()
```

Comment: а вам не проще будет использовать VkSDK ?

Comment: Используйте api
https://github.com/python273/vk_api